# BSOD BlueScreen

Tags: windows, windows-7

Приветствую.

Не давно (т.е. хз от чего) у компьютера с периодичностью в один раз в день начал появляться  синий экран (в самом низу которого написано Crash Dump) и через пару секунд он перезагружался. Обычно запускается после этого без проблем (относительно). После входа появляется окошко и текст :

Сигнатура проблемы:

- Имя события проблемы:    BlueScreen
- Версия ОС:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
- Код языка:   1049

Дополнительные сведения об этой проблеме:

- BCCode: c5
- BCP1:    00000000001AB2C8
- BCP2:    0000000000000002
- BCP3:    0000000000000000
- BCP4:    FFFFF80002E08000
- OS Version:  6_1_7600
- Service Pack:0_0
- Product: 256_1

ОС Виндоус 7. ВНИМАНИЕ ВОПРОС: Что делать чтоб это прекратилось? :)

ps. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для начала отключите автоматическую перезагрузку - Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Система - Дополнительные параметры - Загрузка и восстановление (параметры"") снять галку "выполнить автоматическую перезагрузку". Ппри BSOD (см. скриншот http://hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2012/01/6a5d30fd3cf71c9adf095722326dbb0d.jpg) обратите внимание на код  после слова STOP (0x0000007e на скриншоте) и какой файл вызвал сбой.

Answer (score 1):

Синий экран появляется в том, случае если происходит ошибка на уровне ядра системы, например, драйверов. Поэтому шаги такие:

- откатить состояние системы на несколько шагов назад, используя восстановление системы,
- просканировать систему на вирусы, особенно те, которые живут в MBR,
- обновить систему и драйвера до последних версий,
- просмотреть лог событий на предмет наличия ошибок (eventvwr.msc),
- вернуть настройки в диспетчере устройств на умолчания, если что-то менялось (devmgmt.msc),
- вернуть настройки BIOS на умолчания,
- убедиться, что система собрана аккуратно (если разбиралась-собиралась),
- провести тесты памяти, процессора и жесткого диска (возможно сбой железа),
- запуститься в минимальной конфигурации.

Также если есть подозрения на драйвера, можно поиграть с WinDbg (или тулами вроде WhoCrashed), чтобы определить, кто падает.